# Error in Y * 0: non numeric argument to binary operator - RNN

Tags: r, recurrent-neural-network

Good Morning,

I am currently trying to run a Recurrent Neural Network for Regression, using the package "rnn" on a dataset, called BostonHousing of numerical values; specifically, this is the structure:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1038 obs. of 3 variables: 
$ date : Date, format: "2013-11-19" "2013-11-20" "2013-11-21" "2013-11-22" ... 
$ Quantità : num 0.85 0.85 -0.653 -0.653 -0.653 ... 
$ Giacenza_In: num 0.945 1.648 -0.694 -0.694 -0.694 ...

#Split into train and test
cutoff = round(0.8*nrow(BostonHousing))

train_x <- BostonHousing[1:cutoff,]
test_x <- BostonHousing[-(1:cutoff),]

str(train_x)
#I apply the model and remove the first column because it's made up of dates

require(rnn)
model <- trainr( Y = train_x[,2], 
                 X = train_x[,3],
                 learningrate = 0.05,
                 hidden_dim = 4,
                 numepochs = 100)

pred <- predictr( model, test_x[,3])
```

Whenever I try to run the code, it gives me the error reported in the title.

Basically, I would like to predict "Quantità"(which means Quantity ordered), given the quantity of products currently in stock(Giacenza_In)

Best Regards, Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

It seems like trainr in the package rnn needs binary format to the input and output values. So you have to convert each column using "**int2bin**"

Due to this, first of all you have to convert your numeric values into integer values (using round and multiplying by 10^n)

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1038 obs. of 3 variables: 
$ date : Date, format: "2013-11-19" "2013-11-20" "2013-11-21" "2013-11-22" ... 
$ Quantità : num 0.85 0.85 -0.653 -0.653 -0.653 ... 
$ Giacenza_In: num 0.945 1.648 -0.694 -0.694 -0.694 ...

#Split into train and test
cutoff = round(0.8*nrow(BostonHousing))

train_x <- BostonHousing[1:cutoff,]
test_x <- BostonHousing[-(1:cutoff),]

str(train_x)
#I apply the model and remove the first column because it's made up of dates
n<-5 #Number of decimal values
require(rnn)
model <- trainr( Y = int2bin(round(train_x[,2])*10^n), 
                 X = int2bin(round(train_x[,3])*10^n),
                 learningrate = 0.05,
                 hidden_dim = 4,
                 numepochs = 100)

pred <- predictr( model, int2bin(round(test_x[,3])-10^n))
pred[pred>=0.5]<-1
pred[pred<0.5]<-0
```

And then you have to convert the binary values into integer again

Comment: Briefly, I standardised every input and then split into train and test set; since I'm trying to predict a Quantity. Why does it just display 8 values, when I try to run predictr(model, int2bin...)?